# css style is appending only once in directive, i want the style continuously when we clicks button

Tags: html, css, angularjs

I am trying to use css style in directive, the style is coming but it is not coming continuously when I am clicking the button. 
For example, I have a button and a css style(bouncing style) and also I am having a directive.
If I click that button many times that bouncing style also have to come continuously , but I am not getting the style continuously.
I also used $`watch` in that also only once the style is coming.

```
<div class="row">
<button class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="qty=qty-1">-</button>
<span my-directive="qty" class="box " ng-bind="qty">{{qty}}</span>
<button id="target" class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="qty=qty+1">+</button>
```

```
angular.module('docsSimpleDirective', []).controller('Controller', ['$scope', function($scope) {
$scope.qty =1;  }]).directive('myDirective', function() {
return {
  restrict:'A',
  link:function(scope,elem,attr){
     var btn = document.getElementById('target');
  btn.addEventListener('click', moveMe);

  function moveMe() {
    console.log("coming to move");
    elem.addClass('bounce');
  }

 /* scope.$watch(attr.myDirective, function (newValue, oldValue) {
    if (newValue !== oldValue) {
      console.log("$watch");
      console.log(newValue, oldValue);
      elem.addClass('bounce');

    }
  });*/


  }

}; });
```

Here is my [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/ep3xqnmRjXsClilSqREk?p=preview)

Can you please solve my problem?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to remove class *bounce* after execution of ***moveMe*** function. Can use callback function.

```
function moveMe() {
   console.log("coming to move");
   elem.addClass('bounce');
   setTimeout(function() {
      elem.removeClass('bounce');
   }, 1000);
}
```

Comment: i tried using callback but didn't work can you show me in my plunker @Lovepreet

Comment: thanks ,it works but when we click the button repeatedly then the style didn,t come, so i want when the qty value changes the css style have to come , if we use setTimeout then it takes some time to leave thet class, when value changes immeadeatly again the css style have to come @Lovepreet